# Microsoft Merge replication for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, database-replication, merge-replication

Microsoft Sync Toolkit is extensible by design and allows you to connect databases on Android and iOS clients to sync.

Can you get Merge replication to work with iOS and Android?